# What do ppMediaTypeMixed and ppMediaTypeOther refer to?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have a PowerPoint macro to go through all PowerPoint files in a given path and check for anything of interest.

My code runs. At one point I'm checking for embedded videos or sound by using the `shape.mediatype` property.

I found this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.ppmediatype to know what I can expect to find with this property but I have no idea what `ppMediaTypeMixed` or `ppMediaTypeOther` are and Microsoft telling me "It's mixed media!" doesn't help.

What do these two represent?

Code for the macro (still a WIP).

```vb
Sub PowerPoint_Check_v2()

Dim fldpath As String
Dim filepath As String
Dim Longsum As String
Dim Shortsum As String

Dim com As Comment
Dim pres As Presentation
Dim hyp As hyperlink
Dim sld As Slide
Dim dsg As Design
Dim cstmly As CustomLayout
Dim shape As shape

Dim totnote As Long
Dim tothyp As Long
Dim sldcom As Long
Dim totcom As Long
Dim curdsg As Long
Dim dsgcstmly As Long
Dim hypsld As Long
Dim totchart As Long
Dim sldchart As Long
Dim cursld As Long
Dim hidsld As Long

fldpath = UserForm1.TextBox1.Text & "\"
filepath = Dir(fldpath & "*.ppt*")

'loop through all ppt/pptx/pptm in that path
Do While filepath <> ""
    totchart = 0
    tothyp = 0
    sldchart = 0
    cursld = 1
    hidlsd = 0
    curdsg = 1
    tothyp = 0
    
    On Error Resume Next 'for testing so I do not have to to delete the folders every time since it overwrites the files
    MkDir (fldpath & "Detailled reports")
    MkDir (fldpath & "Short Summary reports")
    
    Shortsum = fldpath & "Short Summary reports\ShortSum_" & filepath & ".txt"
    Longsum = fldpath & "Detailled reports\DetailRep_" & filepath & ".txt"
        
    Open Shortsum For Output As #1
    Open Longsum For Output As #2
    
    Set pres = Application.Presentations.Open(fldpath & filepath)
    With pres
        Print #1, "filename: " & .Name
        Print #1, "Total number of slides: " & .Slides.Count
        
        Print #2, "filename: " & .Name
        Print #2, "Total number of slides: " & .Slides.Count
    
    'count master designs
       Print #1, "Number of master designs: " & .Designs.Count
       Print #2, "Number of master designs: " & .Designs.Count
       
    'count custom layouts
        For Each dsg In .Designs
            For Each cstmly In .SlideMaster.CustomLayouts
                If cstmly.Shapes.Count <> 0 Then
                    dsgcstmly = dsgcstmly + 1
                End If
            Next
            Print #2, "Master design " & curdsg & " has " & dsgcstmly & " custom layouts"
            curdsg = curdsg + 1
            dsgcstmly = 0
        Next
      
    'go through all slides and ungroup everything to avoid missing anything
        Do While cursld < .Slides.Count
            For Each sld In .Slides
                For Each shape In sld.Shapes
                    On Error Resume Next
                    shape.Ungroup
                Next
            Next
            cursld = cursld + 1
        Loop
        
    'Start looking through each slide
        For Each sld In .Slides
        Print #2, "------------Slide " & sld.SlideNumber & "------------"
        'check if hidden
            If sld.SlideShowTransition.Hidden = msoTrue Then
                hidsld = hidsld + 1
                Print #2, vbTab & "-Is Hidden "
            Else: Print #2, vbTab & "-Is vsible"
            End If
            
        'check for speaker note
            If sld.NotesPage.Shapes(2).TextFrame.TextRange.Text <> "" Then
                If sld.NotesPage.Shapes(2).TextFrame.TextRange.Characters.Count > 1 Then
                    totnote = totenote + 1
                    Print #2, vbTab; "-Has speaker notes"
                End If
            Else: Print #2, vbTab & "-No speaker notes"
            End If
        
        'check for comments
            If sld.Comments.Count > 0 Then
                totcom = totcom + 1
                For Each com In sld.Comments
                    sldcom = sldcom + 1
                Next
                Print #2, vbTab & "-Has " & sldcom & " comments"
            sldcom = 0
            Else: Print #2, vbTab & "-Has no comments"
            End If
            
        'start checking shapes
            For Each shape In sld.Shapes
            
        'Check for pictures/dead images
                If InStr(1, shape.Name, "Picture") <> 0 Then
                    sldpic = sldpic + 1
                End If
                
        'check for charts (which could have embedded Excels)
                If shape.HasChart Then
                    sldchart = sldchart + 1
                End If

        'check for embedded media
                If shape.Type = msoMedia Then
                    If shape.MediaType = ppMediaTypeMovie Then
                        Debug.Print ("movie")
                        sldmov = sldmov + 1
                    ElseIf shape.MediaType = ppMediaTypeSound Then
                        Debug.Print ("sound")
                        sldsound = sldsound + 1
                    ElseIf shape.MediaType = ppMediaTypeMixed Then
                        Debug.Print ("mixed") 'the f*** is this?
                    ElseIf shape.MediaType = ppMediaTypeOther Then
                        Debug.Print ("Other") 'the f*** is that?
                    End If
                End If
            Next
            
        'check and print shape chck results
            If sldchart > 0 Then
                totchart = totchart + 1
                Print #2, vbTab & "-There are " & sldchart & " charts with an embedded Excel."
            Else: Print #2, vbTab & "-No chart present."
            End If
            
            If sldpic > 0 Then
                totpic = totpic + 1
                Print #2, vbTab & "-Has " & sldpic & " pictures that might contain text."
            Else: Print #2, vbTab & "-No images present"
            End If
                  
        'check for hyperlinks (skips links to other parts of the presentation)
            If sld.Hyperlinks.Count > 0 Then
                For Each hyp In sld.Hyperlinks
                    If hyp.Address <> "" Then
                        hypsld = hypsld + 1
                    End If
                Next
            End If
            If hypsld > 0 Then
                tothyp = tothyp + 1
                Print #2, vbTab & "-Has " & hypsld & " hyperlinks."
            Else: Print #2, vbTab & "-No Hyperlinks."
            End If
            
            sldpic = 0
            sldchart = 0
            hypsld = 0
        Next
    .Close
    End With
pog:    filepath = Dir 'clear filepath so that it can loop to the next one
    Print #1, _
    hidlsd & " hidden slides" & vbLf _
    ; totnote & " slides with speaker notes" & vbLf _
    ; totcom & " slides with comments" & vbLf _
    ; totpic & " slides with dead images" & vbLf _
    ; totchart & " slides with charts" & vbLf _
    ; tothyp & " slides with hyperlinks"
    Close #1
    Close #2
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: I think it's clear. Media is video, sound, something other, or two or more of those. See at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.shaperange.mediatype the sample code on how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

ppMediaTypeMixed should probably only apply to ShapeRange objects, not individual Shapes.  If you insert a video and a sound file, then select both, then

```
MsgBox ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.MediaType
```

will tell you it's a -2, or ppMediaTypeMixed. I doubt you'd ever get this result back from an individual shape, and even if you grouped the vid and sound shapes, the group wouldn't be a media object.

Comment: That would make sense, since I've tried adding random videos and sound bytes to slides to see what comes out but I've never managed to get a ppMediaTypeMixed result even though all the videos I was adding had both sound and video.
since I'm ungrouping everything in the code to avoid missing anything of interest that would be hidden in a group I guess I can just ignore it then.

Thanks!